# CircleCI + Cypress configuration

Tags: testing, cypress, circleci-2.0

Hello I am having problem with setting up CircleCi together with Cypress.

I included docker image with all necessarry dependencies but still it doesnt work. I tried about 40 different configs without any positive result. Please check my config and output attached in screenshots below.

[image]

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:9.2.0

      - image: circleci/mongo:3.4.4
      - image: cypress/base:8

working_directory: ~/repo

steps:
  - checkout

  - restore_cache:
      keys:
      - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
      - v1-dependencies-

  - run: yarn install

  - save_cache:
      paths:
        - node_modules
      key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}

  - run: yarn test   // THIS COMMAND RUNS UNIT TESTS - and it is working ok

  - run: yarn run dev & $(npm bin)/cypress run // THIS ONE IS FAILING
```

I also realised that if I remove images for node/mongo and run only e2e tests It is working. The problem occures when I try to run both - unit and e2e tests with three docker images.

Comment: Is this an open source project? If not, could you provide a repo with replicable example code so others can test it? Also, screenshots are rarely as helpful as copy-pasting actual text.

Comment: Amended as requested. It is private repo but I am happy to invite you if you know how to fix it.

Comment: Which instance do you want your tests to _run on_? If removing the other two makes things work, maybe just move Cypress to be the first listed image?

Comment: I tried to do so as well

Answer (score 3):

I tried [bkcura's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51081414/5784648) but it didnt work and the same error still appear.

So I tried to use the new Circle feature (orbs) to mix two orbs:

- [React](https://github.com/thefrontside/circleci-react-orb)
- [Cypress](https://github.com/cypress-io/circleci-orb)

And it works

Here's my **config.yml**:

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1
  react: thefrontside/react@0.1.0
workflows:
  push:
    jobs:
      - react/install
      - react/test:
          requires:
            - react/install
  build:
    jobs:
      - cypress/run:
          yarn: true
          start: yarn start
          wait-on: 'http://localhost:3000'
          no-workspace: true
```

Repo with demo: https://github.com/jeanbauer/create-react-app-cypress-circle-ci

Note: Probably this is not that efficient so if you see any improvements please send me an issue [here](https://github.com/jeanbauer/create-react-app-cypress-circle-ci)

Answer (score 1):

See the docs here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Example-circle-yml-v2-config-file-with-yarn

You need to not cache `node_modules`, and instead cache `~/.cache`:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: cypress/base:8
        environment:
          ## this enables colors in the output
          TERM: xterm
    working_directory: ~/app
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-deps-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            - v1-deps-{{ .Branch }}
            - v1-deps
      - run:
          name: Install Dependencies
          command: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
      - save_cache:
          key: v1-deps-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          paths:
            - ~/.cache  ## cache both yarn and Cypress!
      - run: $(yarn bin)/cypress run --record --key <record_key>
```

### Why?

Cypress installs a prebuilt platform specific binary outside of your project folder, in `~/.cache/Cypress` this thing is ~200mb and it takes some time to download, so you should cache it.

Also it only installs on `postInstall`, which won't happen if you cache `node_modules`, hence the error message =)