# CircleCI setup with Cypress and React-testing-library

Tags: cypress, circleci, react-testing-library, circleci-2.0

I would like to use CircleCi to run my Cypress and react-testing-library tests because I want to test my react app.
On local env I would run (which work fine):

- `yarn run test` to execute my react-testing-library tests
- `yarn cypress run` to execute Cypress test

Now, I have found resources on how to make circleci `config.yaml` however nothing have worked. For reference [link1](https://github.com/jeanbauer/cra-rtl-cypress-circleci), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61289532/run-cypress-and-jest-on-circleci), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817161/how-to-specify-node-version-in-circleci-cypress-orb), [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222410/circleci-cypress-configuration), [link5](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images/tree/master/base)

Some of the tests failed due to: `error cypress@7.1.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=12.0.0". Got "10.24.1"` or wrong cashing or something else. After 20 runs I am clueless, can someone help me, please?

As I was browsing resources I thought this should work for Cypress tests but it did not.

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1
workflows:
  build: 
    jobs:
      - cypress/install:
          build: yarn run build # run a custom app build step
          yarn: true
      - cypress/run:
          requires:
            - cypress/install
          parallel: true # split all specs across machines
          parallelism: 4 # use 4 CircleCI machines to finish quickly
          yarn: true
          group: 'all tests' # name this group "all tests" on the dashboard
          start: yarn start # start server before running tests
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who will search this issue later. I overcome errors:

- `error cypress@7.1.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=12.0.0". Got "10.24.1"` by not using orb and instead use `workflow` -> `jobs` -> `steps`
- `fsevents not accessible from jest-haste-map` by using `yarn` instead of `npm`
- Lastly, some of your errors may come from your app (at least in my case react app) taking configuration from `.env` file that is not uploaded to github and therefore is not checkout to CircleCI docker and therefore during the test of the app will not work.

The working solution that I am using is:

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  run_tests:
    docker:
      - image: cypress/base:12
        environment:
          # this enables colors in the output
          TERM: xterm
    working_directory: ~/portalo
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install project dependencies
          command: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
      - run: 
          name: Compile and start development server on port 3000
          command: yarn startOnPort3000Linux
          background: true
      - run: 
          name: Wait for development server to start
          command: 'yarn wait-on http://localhost:3000'
      - run: 
          name: Run routing tests with react-testing-library via yarn test
          command: 'yarn test ~/portalo/src/tests/react-testing-library/routing.test.tsx'
      - run: 
          name: Run e2e tests with Cypruss via cypress run
          command: $(yarn bin)/cypress run

workflows:
  version: 2.1
  build_and_test:
    jobs:
      - run_tests
```

**Note**: `wait-on` had to be added. In my case by `yarn add wait-on`

**Note2**: All steps have to be in a single to have present all installed packages. It could be tweet by using save/restore cache.